# Proper conversion of \u000D \u000A in Java2Javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, encoding, string-comparison

I send data from HTML-Text-Areas to a JSP which inserts them into a database.

If the page is reloaded the database-records are put in this Text-Area and in a JavaScript variable.
The variable is used to determine whether the user has changed the value of the Text-Area or not.

The testing procedure in JavaScript is pretty basic and works most of the time:

```
if(orig_info != document.getElementById('info').value)
//Something has changed!
```

Now it occurs that in some cases even though nothing has changed the change-procedure is called. I checked the text-area and the variable with firebug and it's the same text.
That was odd, so I read the length of both strings:

```
document.getElementById('info').value.length    231     
orig_info.length                                235
```

Yet I couldn't see any difference of 4 Characters so I made a simple output: Letter-Number, Letter, Unicode16 of the Letter and got that:
First one is the Text-Area: `document.getElementById('info').value`, second one is the variable `orig_bemerkung`

```
61  |.  |\u002E|    61  |.  |\u002E
62  |   |\u000A|    62  |   |\u000D
63  |1  |\u0031|    63  |   |\u000A
                    64  |1  |\u0031
```

Now I see it's the old problem with `\u000D` and `\u000A`.

I don't know how to solve that. On the Server I write the following code:

```
ret.append("\ndocument.getElementById('info').innerHTML='").append(StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript(this.getInfo())).append("';");

ret.append("orig_info = '").append(StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript(this.getInfo())).append("';\n");

return ret.toString();
```

Even though, both time exactly the same code is used the Text-Area deals with its content different than the variable.
How can i solve my problem that `orig_info` equals `document.getElementById('info').value` even though, someone used Enter in the Text-Area before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules for HTML form posts explicitly state that `<textarea>` values must be transmitted with CR-LF pairs for hard line breaks typed by the user. Browsers (all of them I think, even newer IE versions) inexplicably return `<textarea>` values to JavaScript code with hard line breaks indicated with LF alone.

You can account for this weirdness by converting your values yourself. It's something like this:

```
function realValue( textareaValue ) {
  textareaValue = textareaValue.replace(/([^\r]|^)\n/g, "$1\r\n");
  return textareaValue;
}

// ...

var xmitValue = realValue( someTextArea.value );
```

Comment: That's a great idea!
By now I went the easy way and changed 
`orig_info = document.getElementById('info').value.replace(/([^\r]|^)\n/g, "$1\r\n");`

The rest is a bigger deal due to some separate ways to send, but it solved my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Yes that's fine; I was just trying to make a clear example. Glad it worked; I don't know why this particular weird corner of the web programming world doesn't get  much attention.

Comment: Unfortunately you're right. For the past months I thought my logic was lacking sometimes but couldn't find a solution. Today as i started to compare the strings manually.
In my opinion in 98% of the cases CR-LF are not relevant because either the problem keeps not being a problem or hardly anyone uses equipment which actually makes a difference (like old printers).
At least now I'm the 2% ;)